# Добавление локальной базы данных (.sdf) в VS2015

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.
Проблема собственно в заголовке - только начал учить С Шарп по предложенной здесь же книге Head First C#. Но все уроки в ней на основе старой версии VS. Как добавить local database, программа предлагает только service-based database.
Догадываюсь, что я не первый с этим вопросом, так что заранее извиняюсь.

Answer (score 6):

**1. Открываем Server explorer**

[image: Открываем Server explorer]

**2. Добавляем новое соединение**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**3. В качестве источника выбираем файл**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**4. Создаем или выбираем существующий *.mdf**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**5. Локальная БД MSSQL готова к работе**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Как выяснилось, в инсталяторе **VS2015**,в дефолтную конфигурацию не входят **Microsoft SQLServer Data Tools**, поэтому если при установке использовалась дефолтная конфигурация, нужно запустить инсталятор еще раз, выбрать пункт `Modify` и выбрать для установки недостающие инструметы работы с данными.

Comment: В общем и прочем - Local Database (Item) в 2015й версии больше не поддерживается, пришлось ставить 2010й Экспресс

Comment: @Генрих так он вроде по дефолту ставится, у меня вообще Local DataBase 2016 стоит, но честно говоря не помню от чего она, возможно вместе с SSMS 2016 встала, но вероятнее всего все таки со студией. В любом случае хорошо, что все получилось

Comment: @Генрих ну вот еще на MSDN инструкцию нашел https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms233763(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2