# Не получается добавить базу данных к проекту на с# в visual studio?

Tags: c#, база-данных, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Создаю проект windows form, далее иду во вкладку - проекты - добавить новый элемент,  в шаблонах выбираю - база данных, основанная на службах - нажимаю добавить и вылезает ошибка "Для подключений к файлам баз данных SQL Server(*.mdf) на локальном компьютере должен быть установлен и запущен LocalDB или SQL Server Express ... "? Visual Studio 2017. Я новичок в этом деле, не судите строго) Кто знает что здесь не так? В установщике смотрел галочка напротив LocalDB стоит. Или ее надо как то запускать до?

Comment: посмотрите тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607588/198316, там про VS 2015 аналогичный вопрос был, есть вероятность что в VS 2017 тоже самое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно по другому создать Подключения - файл бд меняешь на microsoft sql server - имя сервера - (localdb)\v11.0 - ок