# как к visual studio c# подключить базы данных SQL Server”

Tags: c#

как к visual studio c# подключить базы данных SQL Server?

Comment: `Tools -> connect to database`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607588/198316 там про файловый вариант. Незначительно отличается только в 3 и 4 пунктах от подключения полноценного SQL сервера. Ну и на самый последний абзац обязательно обратите внимание.